# what's mean ui/grid/cells/html of bodyTmpl magento 2 grid

Tags: php, magento2, uicomponents

```
<item name="`bodyTmpl`" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
```

the column in `ui_component` can output the html
but I don't know how it can do it
and how I can output data with .html file using bodyTmpl?

Answer (score 1):

bodyTmpl is the **ActionsColumn component**

The ActionsColumns component implements a table’s column responsible for displaying and performing a list of record-related actions.

for all component with detail please read magento official documentation

[Magento Documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-actionscolumn.html)